# Scrollable Div appearing smaller in IE and Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, internet-explorer

I have a scrollable `div` in `td`. It appears fine in Chrome however becomes really small in IE and Firefox but the height of the row stays the same. I have tried to change `overflow:auto` to `overflow:hidden` as suggested by some of the previous answers but nothing seem to work.

Additionally added `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />` to support browswer compatibility but still didn't work.

Height of the table row:

```
#inrm .quotelog {
height: 200px;
}
```

scrollable div

```
#inrm .scrollable {
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
margin: 0px;
padding: 0px;
overflow: auto;
}
```

Inserting the div in HTML as

```
 <tr class="quotelog">
    <td>
        <div class="scrollable"><%=rsOrderView("orderlog")%></div>
    </td>
 </tr>
```

Any suggestion or pointers would be appreciated.

Comment: height: 100%; is never a good practise to use. Why don^t you just set it to 200px aswell, instead of 100%?

Comment: Awesome pinki !!! Thanks a lot, but why is it a bad practise ?

Comment: It's not crossbrowser compatible. :)